# How to change windows build version name in Flutter?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

My version of Flutter is 3.3.6.

I created a Windows exe application with Flutter, but its version number has always been 1.0.0.0. I tried to change the version in pubspec.yaml, which has no effect. I tried to pass parameters in the packaging command, but it didn't take effect.

```
fvm flutter build windows --build-name=1.0.3 --build-number=3
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: is your flutter project was initially built on old version ?

Comment: Yes, I first created the project with Flutter 3.0.2, and then upgraded the version. Is it because I created it with the old version?

Comment: @Manish Dayma, Thanks. I used 3.3.6 to create the project and took effect.

Answer (score 1):

**1- change version in pubspec.yaml [image: pic1]**

**2- run command:**

```
flutter build windows --build-name=1.0.3 --build-number=3
```

[image: pic2]

Comment: Thanks. I used 3.3.6 to create the project and took effect.

Comment: @sanyanl good for you...

Answer (score 0):

Your project can be updated using these steps:

1. Verify you are on Flutter version 3.3 or newer using `flutter --version`
2. If needed, use flutter upgrade to update to the latest version of the Flutter SDK
3. Backup your project, possibly using git or some other version control system
4. **Delete** the `windows/runner/CMakeLists.txt` and `windows/runner/Runner.rc files`
5. Run `flutter create --platforms=windows .`
6. Review the changes to your `windows/runner/CMakeLists.txt` and `windows/runner/Runner.rc files`
7. Verify your app builds using `flutter build windows`

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/windows/version-migration